# How to skip model's method(after_save method) when creating object with Factory Girl

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I have the model A that has many model B, in model B has its method to do something after it is saved. How to skip it?

Comment: This sounds like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/284887) to me. Would you mind sharing your code and the reason why you need to skip the callback? It feels to me like your callback shouldn't be a callback, but a method that is called explicitly instead. IMHO if something is hard to test, it might indicate that the software designed needs to be changed.

Comment: Read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". We need more information.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to skip a callback using factory_girl's `after(:build)` callback.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :model_b do
    after(:build) {|model_b| model_b.class.skip_callback(:save, :after, :your_callback)}
  end
end
```

The factory_girl wiki has a great [example file](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/wiki/Example-factories.rb-file) showing how to use some of the options the library provides.